# Господа, прошу помочь с парсером на BeautifulSoup. Консоль ничего не выдает

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Вот код:
'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://news.google.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
print(f'[INFO] Получен ответ {r}')
html = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
print('[INFO] Обработка BeautifulSoup завершена')
for el in html.select(".VDXfz+h3>a"):
  print(f'- {el.text}')
```

'''
, а консоль ничего не выдает, вот фото: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Динамичексий сайт. Попробуйте селенимум.

Comment: окей, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[INFO] Получен ответ <Response [200]>
[INFO] Обработка BeautifulSoup завершена
- Paul Pelosi attack: Violent details emerge of San Francisco assault
- Trump aides eye third week of November for 2024 announcement
- Former Trump Adviser Acquitted on Charges of Acting as Emirati Agent
- Threat to NJ synagogues 'mitigated' as FBI finds person responsible, Jewish security group says
- Powerball's jackpot is $1.6 billion, the largest lottery prize ever. If you win, here's how much would go to taxes
- This Pennsylvania voter feels something just wasn't right in the 2020 vote. So he'll be watching the midterms up close
```

Это ваш код в работе, возможно вы делали слишком много обращений и сайт заподозрил,что работает скрипт.Почитайте про заголовки и делайте запросы связаной сессией:

```
sess = requests.Session()
r = sess.get(url, headers=HEADERS) # так будет выглядеть запрос в сессии киньте в заголовки User-agent
```